# sorting nested documents with pymongo

Tags: python, tornado, pymongo

how do i sort nested documents:

```
produits = self.db.users.find({"email":email}, {"produit_up":1,"_id":0}).sort(("produit_up.namep"), pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

this dont work!

here is my schema:

```
user={
"pseudo":pseudo,
"email":email, 
"avatar":avatar_id
"produit_up":{
"namep":namep, 
"prix":prix, 
}
}
```

everything worked without sorting, i just use produits = self.db.users.find_one({"email":email})["produit_up"] and in my templates i just call :

```
{% for produit in list(produits) %}
{{ produit["namep"] }}  
{{ produit["prix"] }}
....
{% end %}
```

so how do i do the same if i use `SORT` and `LIMIT` and then return the `namep` for example or `prix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the tip is to use the python list, and then, sort it with a key
[How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/in-python-how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

```
# find_one document with sort.
db.produit.find_one({"email": "email"}, { "produit_up" : 1,"_id" : 0 }, sort=[("produit_up.namep", 1)])

# find all document with sort and limit at last 10 document.
db.produit.find({"email": "email"}, { "produit_up" : 1,"_id" : 0 }, sort=[("produit_up.namep", 1)]).limit(10)
```

Comment: thank you, but finally, it seems that it's only made using Agregate
http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/1b38ecae19ef71af/abfb902771315456?lnk=gst&q=alabdelouahab#abfb902771315456